# Is this a good "random page" PHP code?

Tags: php, arrays, url, math, random

```
<?php 
    $urls = array (
    "id=1.php",
    "id=2.php",
    "id=3.php" ); 
    $random = (rand()%3); 
    header ("Location: ".$urls[$random]);
    exit;
?>
```

I suspect that it could be better, especially because I have to manually edit the % value every time I add a new one.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$random = mt_rand(0, count($urls) -1);`?

Comment: Hi, my suggestion is that not to keep dynamic pages as user get confused when redirect a specific url.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Shouldn't it be `$random = mt_rand(0, count($urls) - 1);` ?

Comment: @Annshuk Well, the above code is my index.php. It's supposed to bring the user to a random page.

Comment: I'll try that, Charlotte and Saqib

Comment: @SaqibAmin Yup, fixed! :3

Comment: May I ask what the -1 is for? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_rand()` function for fetching one or more random keys in an array.

`$random = $urls[array_rand($urls)];`

In comparison to the `mt_rand(0, count($urls) - 1);`, the syntax obviously is clearer, but the randomness algorithm is not so good. Some good candidates for using `array_rand()` are when you are working with arrays with smaller number of elements. There appear to be issues when the number of elements reaches the integer limit, and some issues in Windows. Also it does not provide cryptographically secure numbers, which is a pretty specific topic. Personally I have used this function a lot in **non-critical** contexts such as testing, without running into any issues, but be aware until PHP will use mt_rand algorithm for array_rand() as described in [Bug #45301 Serious flaw in array_rand()](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45301).

Comment: Is this the same as `$random = mt_rand(0, count($urls) - 1);`?

Comment: Updated the answer with a comparison to `mt_rand(0, count($urls) - 1);`

Comment: I did some reading on array_rand and mt_rand, and people generally agree that array produces weird and uneven random distributions, and to go with mt. Just letting you, and anyone reading know.

Comment: I also noticed that and found open bugs on PHP about that; added description of the issues and my own experience.